# Scroll view button action is not working when animating

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, core-animation, uianimation

Added 10 `UIButtons` in a `UIScrollView`. Wrote automatically scroll the scrollview code using `UIAnimation`.

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(XPosition, YPosition, width,50);
    [button setTitle:@"Warning animation items array " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.tag = i;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    if (index%2) {
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    } else{
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    }
    XPosition = paddingSpace + XPosition + button.frame.size.width;
    [_scroll addSubview:button];
    index++;
}
_scroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(XPosition,50);
```

When animating the `UIScrollView`, I can't able tap any `UIButton`!!!

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:20
                      delay:0.0
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat)
                 animations:^{
                     _scroll.contentOffset = CGPointMake(XPosition, 0.0);
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

If the animation is stop only I can tap the `UIButton`.

Please help me out this.

Comment: Put your code of animation.

Comment: Why you can use the scrollview with 10 buttons. Can you use tableview with reuse the same button is a better way. share your code

Comment: Need to scroll vertically repeatedly. I need to tap when animating the scroll

Answer (score 0):

you can use scrollview.userintreactionenable=yes;
i think this help for you